# What are these syringes called?

Tags: home-medical-equipment, instruments, needles

[image]

I have a syringe that looks a lot like this. I'm not using it for medical purposes, but rather to create vacuum and pressure in hoses for testing out fuel delivery in small motors. When I look up syringes to buy it usually comes up with what are called "Luer taper", "Luer-Lok" and "Luer-Slip (registered trademarks), or generically "Luer-Lock" and "Luer-Slip". These look very different from the image posted above. If we take a look one example of a "Luer-Slip" syringe, they usually look like this:

[image]

The first problem being (for my purposes) that the syringe tip or opening is larger than I would like, and the second is that it's not tapered. I would ideally need both (tapered and smaller) to jam them into hoses/lines to get a decent seal.

Does anyone know what these type of syringes are called? I'm trying to search for them at different places.

The one I have and the one in the first image are curved, I don't know if they have a particular name, but I only need a straight one.

As another example, here are some sold on eBay:

[image]

The one on the left is close to what I'm looking for, but I would want a tapered tip beginning from a smaller size at the tip so I can slide it into a tube and get a good seal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [irrigation syringes](https://www.google.com/search?q=irrigation+syringe) - I'm familiar only with the curved variety but at least on a google images search I see straight ones as well.

That said, I've always used luer-style syringes with an appropriate fitting when using syringes in an equipment context. Major catalog parts suppliers have plastic and metal fittings with just about every conversion you can imagine. For example, if I were testing hoses, I'd get a hose barb fitting.

Comment: Ah yes, irrigation syringe brings up quite a few results of what I'm looking for. Many of them seem to be curved but there are also images of straight ones. On eBay they are almost all curved.

Comment: @Zebrafish Does this answer your question? If it does, you should accept it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of syringes listed as "disposable catheter " that typically have a tapered straight tip. A common size is 60 ml . The tip is "universal" friction fit. I use them for G-tube feeding , they are standard for that application despite the name. I typically use them about 20 times. Then use them for purposes similar to in the question . In quantity of 50 they are available on the net for down to about $ 0.60 each and of course as high a price as you want to pay.There are many brands, I seem to end up with a different one each time.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Disposable catheter brings up results of what I've described, however I think "irrigation syringe" is more common, at least from an image search. These so called irrigation syringes usually have a curved tip.